# VPN Connection Issue

Tags: vpn, port, isa-server

We have Windows ISA Server 2004. I have made some changes as we signed up to a 3rd party spam filter company.

I had to block SMTP traffic to funnel through port 25 and now the VPN connection won't work. mail.domain.com.au won't connect, but ping mail.domain.com.au does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your firewall rule is overly broad. You can monitor the ISA log in realtime to see what's happening with your VPN connection attempts. That's what I'd do.

You don't mention what type of VPN you're using. You should add that to your question, when you get a moment.

Comment: Worked out the issues. There was an issue with our A records in our Domain hoster. They were not updated to our IP address. Thanks for your help.